# rosjava_core in Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosjava-core, rosjava, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to install rosjava_core in Fuerte.
I did:

```
rosws set --git rosjava_core 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core.git'

    rosws update
```

But there seems no manifest.xml present anymore? So I can't roscd in to the folder. I also tried rospack profile but that did not work.

I also got this error  which I fixed (?) by renaming the .rosinstall file

```
ERROR in config: Ambiguous workspace: ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/lennart/fuerte_workspace, /home/lennart/fuerte_workspace/rosjava_core/.rosinstall
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65674/rosjava_core-in-fuerte/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that rosjava was recently catkinized for use with groovy and hydro, and there is no fuerte branch. I've fixed that by forking rosjava and creating a branch just before the catkinization. If you want to use my fork, you can do this:

```
rosws set --git rosjava_core 'https://github.com/uos/rosjava_core.git' --version=fuerte-devel
```

Alternatively, you can try getting the rosjava developers to create a `fuerte-devel` branch so you can do this with the official repo instead of my fork.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-06-24**:
Thanks! Also submitted an issue to the developers.